# Prj missing on all shapefiles

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, prj

I have a problem with my QGIS configuration whereby every shapefile (or KML) I create is missing a prj file and so when I open the shapefile in Google Earth Pro it drops me in the Atlantic Ocean off the coast of Africa rather than in Australia. I've tried the following:

**Step 1:** I have set the project CRS to GDA2020 / EPSG:7842.

Settings -> Options -> CRS for Projects -> When a new project is created use a default CRS ESPG:7842.

CRS for Layers -> Default CRS for layers: EPSG:7842. When a new layer is created "Prompt for CRS".

**Step 2:** I have imported the Google Maps layer and also set the layer CRS to EPSG:7842

Web -> QuickMapServices -> Google -> Google Satellite. Then right click on Google Satellite layer and click Layer CRS -> (CRS is set to ESPG:3857 / WGS 84) click "Set to ESPG:7842".

**Step 3**: I'll then create shapefiles (also saved CRS as EPSG:7842)

**Step 4**: Save as KML

Saving as a shapefile doesn't fix the problem. Going into  QuickMapServices Settings and enabling on the fly projection doesn't change anything. At all stages of the process, I've set the CRS to GDA2020 / ESPG:7842. I'm using QGIS 3.16.10.

Any ideas?

Comment: KML files are always WGS84/Geographic EPSG:4326, it's in the definition. Try EPSG:4283 (GDA94/Geographic) just in case the GDA2020 transformation isn't set up correctly or doesn't want to play ball, that should get you out of the Atlantic and closer to the Pacific even if it's not spot-on.

Comment: KML is not EPSG:4326 ~ `<GeodeticCRS gml:id=“LonLat84”>
      <identifier codeSpace=“http://www.opengeospatial.org/ogcna”>
      http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84
      </identifier>
      <name>WGS 84 with long/lat axis order</name>
      <scope>KML geographic 2D coordinate reference system (adapted from EPSG-4326).</scope>` http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html (OGC KML 2.3)

Comment: Don't change the CRS of the basemap layer, let it be EPSG:3857 and all will be fine. Don't worry about the CRS at export to KML, it will be saved always in its standarized CRS.

Comment: Also, EPSG:7842 is a 3D Cartesian geocentric CRS, isn't a good choice for a 2D map.

Comment: Setting the project and polygons to ESPG:3857 has largely solved the problem. The KMLs I create now show up on Google Earth Pro in the correct location. But when I save it as a shapefile it still doesn't have a prj file (I'm guessing because it's flat rather than projected). And it doesn't solve the problem of if I need to produce a shapefile in a specific projection (which in this case is EPSG:7842 but could be any projection).

Comment: What nmtoken wants to emphasize is that in EPSG:4326 the axis order is latitude-longitude while KML, GeoJSON and lots of GML2 and other data out there use axis order longitude-latitude. Otherwise the coordinates are the same, just in different order. It is good to know that even that lon-lat data if very often called as EPSG:4326, one reason being the EPSG does not have a code for the lon-lat version.